# Download a file from Linux

Tags: linux

How do I download a webpage or a file from linux OS rather than a browser? When the file is locked with user agent.

Comment: You may wish to use the Curl command from within bash.  Checkout the man pages for it to set a user agent header: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)  (cf manual page)

and add  the `--user-agent` option with the right user agent.

You can download a single file like this:

```
wget http://www.example.com/archive.zip
```

or for example an entire ftp directory:

```
wget -r ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)" http://somepage.com/images/pic01.jpg
```